# How do I convert binary/hex array to string array in C

Tags: c, binary, string, hex

in my quest( still starting :) ) to be better at programming I've stumbled upon something that I just cannot answer.

I was tasked to convert binary/hex data (in an array) to string array. So far I've only managed to convert and print the "MSB"s of the hex data.

Here is my current code. Constructive criticism is highly appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;  

    unsigned long rawdata[] ={0x60,0x100,'\0'};

    char stringForRawdata[250];

    char finalString[250];

    while(i<2)
    {
        sprintf(stringForRawdata,"%lx",*(rawdata+i));

        //sprintf(finalString,"%s",stringForRawdata);

        finalString[i] = *(stringForRawdata);

        printf("\nfinalString[%d] = %s",i,finalString+i);

        printf("\nrawdata = %lx for i = %d\n",*(rawdata+i),i); 

        i = i+1;    

    }
    printf("\n stringForRawdata = %s\n",stringForRawdata);
    printf("\n\n finalString array is %s\n",finalString);
 }
```

input is the `unsigned long rawdata[] ={0x60,0x100,'\0'};`

expected output is a string array `{60,100,\0}` or `{0x60,0x100,\0}`

the problem is that I can only get the leftmost digit to my string array.

Comment: I don't think `0x60` is `60` in the string array. Shouldn't it be `96`?

Comment: he prints it with `%lx`, not `%l`, it will be 60 in string array

Comment: do you want `{"0x60","0x100","\0"}` or `"{0x60,0x100,\0}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

On every iteration, print into `finalString + strlen(finalString)`.

Here is an example (assuming that the input array always ends with `'\0'`):

```
int i = 0;
char finalString[250]   = "{";
unsigned long rawdata[] = {0x60,0x100,'\0'};

for (i=0; i<sizeof(rawdata)/sizeof(*rawdata)-1; i++)
    sprintf(finalString+strlen(finalString),"%lx,",rawdata[i]);
sprintf(finalString+strlen(finalString),"\\0}");
```

Please note that `sprintf` is generally unsafe (consider using `snprintf` or `sprintf_s` instead).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    int i, j;`
    unsigned long rawdata[] ={0x60,0x100,'\0'};
    char stringForRawdata[250] = "{";

    int k = sizeof(rawdata)/ sizeof(rawdata[0]), c = 1;

    for(i, j=0; i< k; i++)

    {
        j+=c;        // think why
        c = sprintf(&stringForRawdata[j], "0x%x,", rawdata[i]);
    }
    sprintf(&stringForRawdata[j], "\\0}");
    printf("\nstringForRawdata = %s\n",stringForRawdata);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Suggest changes: 1) `for(i=0, j=0; ` vs. `for(i, j=0;` 2) `"0x%lx,"` vs. `"0x%x,"` 3) `int i, j` remove trailing `.